# AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'

Tags: python, pygame

I keep getting this error. Here's the full traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Luc/PycharmProjects/game_practice/game.py", line 23, in 
<module>
run_game()
File "C:/Users/Luc/PycharmProjects/game_practice/game.py", line 13, in 
run_game
player = Player(ai_settings, screen)
File "C:\Users\Luc\PycharmProjects\game_practice\player.py", line 8, in 
__init__
self.rect.centerx = screen.rect.left
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'rect'
```

Here's the code for the "Player" file that's having an issue:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, ai_settings, screen):
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        self.rect = pygame.Rect((0, 0), (ai_settings.player_width, 
        ai_settings.player_height))
        self.rect.centerx = screen.rect.left
        self.rect.centery = screen.rect.ai_settings.screen_height / 2
        self.color = ai_settings.player_color

    def draw_player(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, self.color, self.rect)
```

When I comment these two lines:

```
self.rect.centerx = screen.rect.left
self.rect.centery = screen.rect.ai_settings.screen_height / 2
```

The program runs with the rectangle initialized at (0,0) like its supposed to, so I am not really sure why the object has an attribute error when I include the other lines.

Answer (score 2):

The `screen` is a pygame.Surface which has no `rect` attribute, but you can get a rect with the size of the surface by calling `screen.get_rect()` what you already do in this line:

```
self.screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
```

Now you just have to use your `self.screen_rect` instead of `screen.rect` and your code should work.

```
# To place the player at the midleft.
self.rect.midleft = self.screen_rect.midleft
```